# Coder on Matlab to C++ , sym and perms function?

Tags: c++, matlab

I am discovering the coder tool in Matlab. some of my code was successfully converted but it fails in functions which contain the functions "sym" for symbolic and "perms" for permutations. Also I seem to get an error when I save the answer "ans" of for example "A==B". Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your help

Here is an example of parts of my matlab function that cannot be transformed into c++ with coder:

```
b=4;
s=2;
one=ones(factorial(b),1);
two=2*ones(factorial(b),1);
B=perms(s+1:b+s);

S=[one,two,B];
sz=size(S);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

L=[1,3;1,4;1,5;1,6;2,3;2,4;2,5;2,6];
x=perms(1:8);
M=[];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some toolbox functions cannot be compiled, i.e. they can only be run from a MATLAB session. The following post tells us that functionality in the Symbolic toolbox cannot be compiled.

http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96441-why-am-i-unable-to-compile-functions-from-the-symbolic-math-toolbox

So most likely this is the reason why you are running into problems when you try to run it in compiled form.

More info about compiler support for various toolboxes can be found here:

http://se.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html

Symbolic Math toolbox does not appear on the list and any toolbox that is not listed is not supported (i.e. cannot be compiled).

Comment: You should try to summary the most relevant parts in the links. This will keep the answer valid even if the links change.

Comment: Updated answer with a summary about the relevant info for the second link.

Comment: Hello, so for "sym" it is not supported but I get an error also for "perms" although it is supported according to the link (perms is in Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox 10.2). Any idea why? thank you

Comment: Can you update your original question with a code sample that I can use to replicate the problem. With the current info I am unable to help you.

Comment: I am sorry just saw your comment thank you very much just edited my post

Comment: and may have edited yours by mistake but I cant seem to be able to delete what I wrote in your answer